# Include custom field in Ajax search Wordpress

Tags: wp-query, ajax, advanced-custom-fields

I have a search form for a custom post type. The user should be able to search by name of the store and the city where the store is located 
The name of the store is the same as the title of the post, so Ive managed to figure that part out. 
The city on the other hand is an advanced custom field, and I can't figure out how to include this in the search query. 
So when the user starts to type, is it a match with 1. the post title and/or 2. the advanced custom field "city"?

This is my code in **functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function fetch(){

     jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
        success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
     }
 });

}
</script>
<?php
}

 // the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');

function data_fetch(){
    if (  esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ) == null ) { die(); }
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'aterforsaljare' ) );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <h2><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>

        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die();
}
```

And the html is as simple as this:

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()"></input>

<div id="datafetch">Search results will appear here</div>
```

This code works as long as the user search for the title of store. How do I manage to include a custom field as an argument (sorry this might be the wrong word but I cant find the right one) to the `WP_query`?

I found [this](https://adambalee.com/search-wordpress-by-custom-fields-without-a-plugin/) example, and I tried it but just got an error saying that `cf_search_join` couldn't be found. And at the same time didn't really manage to understand the code... Is this the more right approach? Or can I build something from what I already have?

** UPDATED QUERY **

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 
    'post_type' => 'aterforsaljare',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'vendor_city',
            'value' => 'value',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        )
    )
) );
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is going to be a very expensive query. If you want this to work quickly, and work well, you should look into setting up elastic search and using a plugin to integrate with it

Answer (score 1):

You can include [meta_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) parametr in your WP_Query.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'country',
        'value' => 'value',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'city',
        'value' => 'value',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
),
```

Comment: After adding this to my WP_Query, no results is given instead.. Not even if I search for the name.

Comment: Show your query. It should work propertly.

Comment: I have updated my post with the query

Comment: Are you changed value on your request variable? Should be 'value' => $_POST['keywords']

Comment: Okay I was a bit ahead of myself. Now it doesn't go for the title, only the city. I changed "value" to `$_POST['keywords']` in the `meta_query` and left the rest of the code as in my example above.